# MySQL запись в базу не происходит

Tags: php, mysql

Вот таким образом произвожу запись в базу:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO horoscope(oven, telec, blizneci, rak, lev, deva, vesi, scorpion, strelec, kozerog, vodoley) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss',$oventodaytext, $telectodaytext, $bliznetcitodaytext, $raktodaytext, $levtodaytext, $devatodaytext, $vesitodaytext, $scorpiontodaytext, $strelectodaytext, $kozerogtodaytext, $vodoleytodaytext);
$stmt->execute();
$mysqli->close();
```

Но ничего не записывается... Через echo проверял, всё отлично выводится, но в базе пусто) Может быть проблема в хостинге (использую 000webhost)?  Если передавать 10 значений в одну строку, то всё работает:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO horoscope(oven, telec, blizneci, rak, lev, deva, vesi, scorpion, strelec, kozerog) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssss',$oventodaytext, $telectodaytext, $bliznetcitodaytext, $raktodaytext, $levtodaytext, $devatodaytext, $vesitodaytext, $scorpiontodaytext, $strelectodaytext, $kozerogtodaytext);
$stmt->execute();
$mysqli->close();
```

Стоит только одиннадцатый параметр записать – уже ничего не записывается...

Сделал проверку на ошибки с помощью предложенного кода, вот что вылезло:

```
execute() failed: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

Вот так создавал таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему кто пишет подобные темы никогда не выкладывает ошибку, что говорит mysqli, mysql, PDO ?

Comment: @ArchDemon никаких ошибок не выводится... Просто в базе пусто и всё

Comment: У вас содержимое 11 переменных случайно не превышает максимально допустимый размер пакета (max_allowed_packet)!?

Comment: вам надо проверить на ошибку и вывести ее вот так http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting

Comment: @Visman вполне может быть. В каждой строковой переменной около 700 символов. А что делать в том случае, если превышает?

Comment: Если там всего по 700 символов, то это не тот случай.

Comment: @Jean-Claude прикрепил полученное вашим способом сообщение об  ошибке к вопросу

Comment: сюда же прикрепите структуру вашей таблицы mysql - CREATE TABLE ... (как вы ее создавали).

Comment: вероятно в Водолее слишком большой объем текста, как вариант сменить поле с text на longtext, а также можно поменять конфигурацию сервера, если есть возможность, пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/39403564/6311482, третий вариант, если у вас таблица InnoDB, перевести её на MyISAM.

Comment: @Jean-Claude прикрепил как создавал. На MyISAM поменял, скрипт вообще ну очень долго стал выполняться, я даже окончания выполнения не дождался... Не знаю, есть ли возможность менять конфиг сервера на бесплатном хостинге 000webhost, но что-то не видел там. Размер текста в каждой переменной не больше 1200 символов.

Comment: Если в проекте используются транзакции, я бы не стал применять MyISAM, только InnoDB. Если longtext не подходит, то тут только CLOB. Но это жесть какая-то. Вы там войну и мир храните?

Comment: Возможно стоит пересмотреть структуру таблицы. Создать таблицу с знаками зодиака где они получать свои id, а в таблице с гороскопом при этом будут нужны только 3 колонки: id-записи, id-знака, текст. т.е. храните все не в одной записи, а в 12 записях. тогда и получать текст по одному знаку будет проще

Comment: @Mike подскажи, 1200 символов в юникоде влазят в поля его таблицы?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Думаю там длина все таки в байтах, тогда конечно не влазят. минимум 2400 надо.

Comment: @Mike пожалуй, так и сделаю )